# How to remove only delete permission about symlink from usual user on Windows

Tags: windows, symlink

We have a program which makes temporary directory `HT` on `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp`and working on there, and delete the temporary directory when I quit the program.
I want to make the program generate its temporary diretory not on `Temp` but SSD partition `F:\Somewhere`.

Unfortunately, the program does not have any settings that to change the temporary directory.
This environment(Windows) is installed in HDD, and have SSD partition. (I can't install Windows on SSD because of some problems.)

So, I think I make symlink `HT` on `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` which direct to `F:\Somewhere`.
It seems to be worked.
However, I couldn't prevent the program delete the symlink `HT`. In other words, I need to make symlink again and again after I quit the program.

How can I prevent deleting the symlink from the program?

### Solution that I tried

I tried to remove deleting permission about symlink `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\HT` from usual user (The program is running by usual user, not UAC-upgraded user).

From Property -> Security -> Advanced(?, my environment is Japanese, but seems to be advanced)
1. Disable permission inheritance
2. Add Reject policy about delete permission for usual user, Administrator, and system

But the program could delete the symlink.

### Summarized Question

How can I prevent deleting symlink to directory from the program which runs not on admin authority?

P.S. sorry for not-usual words. I'm using Japanese windows, so I couldn't found properly matching English phrase.

### Additional notes

- I do not want to change `Temp` directory to another directory/partition completely. Just the directory `HT` only under `~~/Temp/HT`.

Comment: Set the permissions on the parent directory (Temp). Delete/Create permissions have to be set on the parent directory, not the directory/file itself.

Comment: @Gerald, nitpick: [to delete a file or directory](http://campus.mst.edu/cis/desktop/documentation/pc/win7_x64/permissions/index.htm) you need *either* "delete" on the object *or* "delete subfolders and files" on the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the permissions on the symbolic link doesn't work because the "delete subfolders and files" right on the parent directory takes precedence over any permissions on the symlink itself.  I do not recommend modifying the permissions on the parent directory in this case, since a lot of software depends on the temporary directory and any changes to the permissions could cause problems that in many cases would be quite difficult to diagnose.

Instead, you can set the read-only flag on the symlink.  Note that you must do this from the command line, because the Windows Explorer GUI does not support use of the read-only flag for directories (see footnote).  These commands should work:

```
cd /d %temp%
attrib /L +r HT
```

You may also need to change the permissions to prevent the symlink from being moved or having the read-only flag reset:

```
icacls HT /L /deny Everyone:(M)
```

There is still a risk that the software will respond badly to the inability to remove the symlink, e.g., by crashing.  There's nothing much you can do in that case, other than trying to set things up so that the symlink is automatically recreated as necessary, but fortunately this is rare.

*Footnote:*

Explorer also doesn't *show* the read-only flag for directories, and will even go so far as to advise the user that the read-only flag has no effect on directories, which is true from a certain point of view, I suppose, since it doesn't stop the directory from being renamed or moved or the contents being changed as one might have expected.  All that the read-only flag does is to prevent an empty directory (or a directory symlink, regardless of whether the target is empty) from being removed, but in this particular case that's exactly what is needed.

*Side note:*

The specific access rights that need to be blocked are Write Attributes (WA) to prevent the read-only flag being reset and Synchronize (S) to prevent the symlink from being, e.g., moved to the Recycle Bin.  It should be noted that this approach will only work as desired with a directory symlink, not an ordinary directory, because the Synchronize right is required to access the contents of a directory.  There does not appear to be any way in NTFS to prevent an ordinary directory from being moved without changing the permissions on the parent.

Comment: Thanks Harry, this really works well for my purpose.

Answer (score 3):

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` is the default value for the `TMP` and the `TEMP` environment variable. Most probably The application is using this variable to get the temp dir.

Just set the variable to `F:\`, for example [by launching it through a .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036325/can-i-set-an-environment-variable-for-an-application-using-a-shortcut-in-windows), and your symlink should not be needed anymore.

Comment: Yes, it could be. But there are also lots of other program and services. And I just wants to redirect only for a application only.

Comment: There is no need to set this system wide. Just set it for your application before you start it. That's exactly what these variables are for.

Comment: I'm sorry for my question is not clear. I want to leave the `Temp` directory in the HDD. I just wants to redirect for a directory only. In other words, I want to leave other temporary files and folders in original path.

Comment: @QuietJoon, if Gerald is right here about your program (and he probably is) what he suggests will do exactly what you want. You would end up with a folder F:\HT being the only thing redirected. The variable is set right before launching your program, and when the command session ends so does the custom set variable.

Comment: A lot of programs look up the temporary folder directly rather than using the environment variables.  And it may be inconvenient to have to teach the end users to run a batch file instead of the program itself.  Even worse if the program has registered file handlers!  It would be possible to create a compatibility fix that automatically sets the environment variables whenever the program is run, but that isn't straightforward.  So depending on the circumstances, the OPs approach may still be best, and as my answer explains it isn't all that difficult to achieve.